# Viewer3D's getIsolatedNodes and getHiddenNodes not working for multiple models

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm loading multiple IFC's with their SVF derivatives into the Forge viewer. This works fine, but I cannot seem to get the Viewer3D's `getIsolatedNodes` or `getHiddenNodes`to work.

I'm using the `GuiViewer3D` class like this:

```
// initializing: 
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);

...
// load model1 
viewer.start(model1Url ....
...
// load model2
viewer.loadModel(model2Url, ...

...
// after having loaded the models:        
console.log(viewer.getIsolatedNodes());
```

The last line here only prints node ids if `model1` has isolated nodes. If isolating nodes from `model2`, the last line prints an empty array. Is there a way to make this work with multiple models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the viewer's *visibility manager* via `viewer.impl.visibilityManager`, and call its methods for a specific model ID, for example:

```
viewer.impl.visibilityManager.getIsolatedNodes(modelID);
viewer.impl.visibilityManager.getHiddenNodes(modelID);
viewer.impl.visibilityManager.getAggregateHiddenNodes(); // across all models
```